# Using Node.js file system is it smarter to run through 80 files looking for a property than it is to run through conditions in one file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, fs

Let me explain: I am building a node.js project that needs to check if dates match or fall within a range. If there is a match, I need to store a reference to the path of a file on the server. There are about 80 of these files. They are configurations.

I can write a giant condition in a function that can run through and check the dates. It will be fast, I'm sure. The real question is, is it smarter to let each config file store it's own date (the date is a calculation based on a date that will have to be passed in to the config file), then loop through the files, requiring each one, finding the property holding the date, checking it, then either storing the files path or not?

The requiring approach will be much less code, and it will be cleaner, but I'm wondering if I will take a huge performance hit. Is it better to just write a giant list of conditions?

Sorry if this is not clear. Let me know if I need to include anything to help clarify the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I'll just point out that require is a synchronous operation so if this is something that doesn't happen except at application startup you will block on all 80 `require`s

Comment: @StephenByrne: I guess he means `fs.readFile()`, not `require()`

Comment: @Bergi yes perhaps but there's no mention of readFile :)

Comment: I meant require actually. Sorry. I would use export.whatever in the config file itself.   A friend has suggested I create a hash table then require that. The date could be the key and the filename could be the value in an object. If I just require that table I could run a for in loop against it to determine which file to load. Does this sound like a good, clean approach? Bergi's answer below suggests "storing it in memory", the date that is. This "memory" could be the hash table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the date is a calculation based on a date that will have to be passed in to the config file

Then don't put the calculation result in the config file as well, but store it in memory.

On startup, run through all 80 files (in parallel?), collect the dates and do the respective calculations. Store the results in an array or so.
On each request, write a loop (not a giant hand-written condition!) to find the date, and use the file path associated to it.